# Como solucionar Brokenimport en golang al intentar importar un paquete en GO?

Tags: go

Hola a todos estoy intendo importar un paque de GO en un curso basico que estoy tomendo, he intalado go en una macbook pro el GO path lo configure con el comando en echo `"export GOPATH=/Users/anki/Documents/go" >> .bash_profile`

y el proyecto lo tengo en la carpeta
/Users/gerardoguevara/Documents/go/basics/golang-basics

y en este falder tengo el proyecto que basicamente solo tiene la estructura src
pueden verlo aca https://github.com/Gerguevara/golang-basics

adentro tendo todos los ejercicios pero me esta fallando una importacion que hago de un archivo que llama modificadoresDeAcceso.go llamo a un paquete dentro en el mismo proyecto
llamado mypackage y el archivo mypackage.go tiene solamente esto

```
package mypackage
import "fmt"

type CarPublic struct {
    Year  int
    Brand string
}

type privateCar struct {
    year  int
    brand string
}

func PrintMessage() {
    fmt.Println("hola")
}
```

y el archivo donde lo llamo tiene esto

```
package main

import (
    pk "GOLANG_BASICS/src/mypackage/mypackage"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var myCar pk.CarPublic
    fmt.Println(myCar)
}
```

para facilitarlo esta es mi estructura de folder
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero me da este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para ubicar donde tengo el proyecto mas facilmente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como normal general, es recomendable que el path al proyecto sea `$GOPATH/src/repo/url/paquete` y que también sea el nombre del módulo.

en tu caso sería: `GOPATH/src/github.com/Gerguevara/golang-basics`

y luego inicializar el modulo con: `go mod init`

además, no puedes tener más de un `func main()` en el mismo paquete, yo te recomendaría que llamaras todas las funciones de los distintos archivos en `main.go` en vez de tener un main() en cada uno.

Una vez tengas eso corregido podrás importar `mypackage` de la siguiente manera:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    pk "github.com/Gerguevara/golang-basics/mypackage"
)

func someFunction() {
    var myCar pk.CarPublic
    fmt.Println(myCar)
}
```